# neighboring selector css without the ability to change html

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select one of the items submenu #submenu3.0 or #submenu3.1
But since they are not unique, I try to connect them with a neighboring selector. Rewrite html code is not possible

```css
#menu_member_personal + #subMenuContainer3 > #submenu3.0
{ color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="menu3" class=" menu" style="cursor: pointer;">
 <span class="menuBullet"></span>
 <span id="menu_member_personal" class="menuText menuTextActive">Personal</span>
 <script>menuCount++;</script>
 <ul id="subMenuContainer3" class="subMenuContainer" style="overflow: visible;">
  <li id="submenu3.0" class="firstSubMenu subMenu" linkurl="#" style="cursor: pointer; width: 260px;">
   <span class="subMenuBullet"></span>
   <span class="subMenuText subMenuTextActive">Profile</span>
   <script>$('submenu3.0').addClassName('firstSubMenu');</script>
  </li>
  <li id="submenu3.1" class=" subMenu" linkurl="#" style="cursor: pointer; width: 260px;">
   <span class="subMenuBullet"></span>
   <span class="subMenuText">Messages</span>
  </li>
  <li id="submenu3.2" class=" subMenu" linkurl="#" style="cursor: pointer; width: 260px;">
   <span class="subMenuBullet"></span>
   <span class="subMenuText">Contacts</span>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

how to correctly write a selector so that it works and has been tied in a unique id="menu_member_personal"

Comment: There's a ton of unique IDs (BTW thank you), if your target is `#submenu3.0` why not just use `#submenu3.0`? When you say that they are not unique do you mean you have more than one `#submenu3.0` on the page but it's not included in example?

Comment: they are unique on the page, but not unique throughout the site. Like when will admin login or some they have a different menu, but submenus will have such id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `#menu_member_personal ~ #subMenuContainer3 > li:first-child` or `#menu_member_personal ~ #subMenuContainer3 > #submenu3\.0`. `~` instead of `+` since there is a `script` between the two elements.

```css
#menu_member_personal ~ #subMenuContainer3 > #submenu3\.0 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<li id="menu3" class=" menu" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <span class="menuBullet"></span>
  <span id="menu_member_personal" class="menuText menuTextActive">Personal</span>
  <script>
    menuCount++;
  </script>
  <ul id="subMenuContainer3" class="subMenuContainer" style="overflow: visible;">
    <li id="submenu3.0" class="firstSubMenu subMenu" linkurl="#" style="cursor: pointer; width: 260px;">
      <span class="subMenuBullet"></span>
      <span class="subMenuText subMenuTextActive">Profile</span>
      <script>
        $('submenu3.0').addClassName('firstSubMenu');
      </script>
    </li>
    <li id="submenu3.1" class=" subMenu" linkurl="#" style="cursor: pointer; width: 260px;">
      <span class="subMenuBullet"></span>
      <span class="subMenuText">Messages</span>
    </li>
    <li id="submenu3.2" class=" subMenu" linkurl="#" style="cursor: pointer; width: 260px;">
      <span class="subMenuBullet"></span>
      <span class="subMenuText">Contacts</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```